# Почему PyQt6 не устанавливается в виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6, venv

Я пытался установить PyQt6 в виртуальное окружение, но консоль выдает мне ошибки
вот они

running build_ext
building 'sipbuild.code_generator' extension
error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
[end of output]

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
  Failed to build sip
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

что делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получилось установить *PyQt6* только под *Windows 11*, то есть буквально на *Windows 10* просто не получалось, мне выдавало огромное количество ошибок зависимостей, и когда я эти зависимости устанавливал, все равно ничего не получалось, а как только обновился до *Windows 11*, сразу все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

на какую операционную систему ставили виртуальное окружение python, обновляли ли в последнее время библиотеку *pip*, находится ли *pip* в пути `path`?

Попробуйте сделать новое виртуальное окружение, скорее всего вы ставили *PyQt6* в то виртуальное окружение, которое конфликтовало с другими библиотеками (устаревшими).

Также попробуйте `pip install qt6_applications`, `pip install qt6_tools`, `pip install pyqt6_plugins`.

Также может помочь обновление *pip*: `python -m pip install --upgrade`.

И еще может помочь установка *PyQt6-sip*: `python pip install pyqt6-sip`.